# Storing 10M unique records and accessing it efficiently

Tags: java

I came across this interview test question:

> There is long list of alphanumerically sorted names with one phone
>   number next to each one. It is long list containing 10M names and
>   numbers. One time disk pre processing is allowed. After that how would
>   I find a number for a input name without hitting the disk?

My first reaction would be to store all these numbers in a `HashMap <String, String>`. This will `O(1)` runtime to access phone number for a given name. Not sure if Map is the right data structure to store 10M records.

Is there an efficient way of doing that?

Comment: IMHO using `HashMap` is OK, but the `disk pre processing` part bothers me. Maybe there is a better solution ?

Comment: If you do not want to hit the disk, then do not put it on the disk? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @skiwi It may be read from the disk once, but not every time you try to access a value.

Comment: Then it ought to as simple as using a `HashMap<>` indeed, after that it is in memory. Or the question is lacking some details...

Comment: You want a key-value association. That's exactly what `Map`s are for. I don't think you can get it any more efficient than with a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): "This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (`get` and `put`), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets."

Comment: Just stick it in a database, and if that's not good enough for them then go elsewhere.  (Their question is meaningless if they don't specify, at least generally, how much RAM is available.)

Comment: Is the problem that you are concerned about running out of memory?  I can see that being a problem on an embedded system (typically memory isn't allocated into chunks smaller than 32 bytes, and each record would require at least 3 allocations - 1 for each string and one for the node itself).  So for 10M records you're probably looking at around 1GB of memory usage minimum.

Comment: (It should be observed that the number is likely smaller than the name, so if you put the names in a hashmap there's no point in putting the numbers on disk.  Likely what they were fishing for (with lousy bait) was to put the hash buckets on disk, so that you hash the name and that takes you to the right bucket, mapped to a single disk sector.  Search the sector for the name & extract the corresponding number.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed some performance tests and I found that `HashMap` is the most efficinet Map of java API (`List` and `Arrays` are more efficient).

Generally speaking, if phone numbers are ordered and consecutive you can access to the list stored in the file randomly through :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

there are several other techniques (based on hash, tree index,..) which are in the domain od databases (DBs have been developed for this purpose).

However 10M elements are not so big and memory caching through `HashMap` should be ok (more or less 1-4GB).
Concluding, if you need performance **`HashMap` is the correct response.** Indeed, several cache idea are based on Map (Coherence, EHCache, Spring, ...).